# Form Element decorators Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm using Zend Framework 1 and [this](https://github.com/komola/Bootstrap-Zend-Framework) library to integrate Twitter-bootstrap. It's great library, but I want to add new decorators for it (for Zend Form Element File), so that it looked like [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

So instead of

```
<input id="image" type="file" name="image">
```

I want to render something like that (with all styles and javascript)

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
  <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
  <span>Add files...</span>
  <input type="file" multiple="" name="files[]">
</span>
```

I'm new to Zend Framework and do not know how to do that.

The question is, what have I put in library/Twitter/Form.php, in public/css and public/javascript to make it work?

Or maybe I have to do something else?

I tried to add decorators in Form.php, but no decorators applied (I do not remember what I did exactly)

So the main question is, how can I add this decorators for my Element in library/Twitter?

Edited:

I was working on the problem and managed to show a green button with a "plus" picture using jQuery-file-upload-ui.css (do not remember a name of the file) and changing $decorators in Form.php where code

```
if($element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_File)
```

is situated to

```
$decorators = array(
            "ViewHelper",
            array("Errors", array("placement" => "append")),
            array("Description", array("tag" => "span", "class" => "help-block")),
            array(array("ivanov2" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "i", "class" => "icon-plus icon-white",'openOnly' => true,)),
            array(array('close' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'i', 'closeOnly' => true)),
            array(array("ivanov" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "span", "class" => "btn btn-success fileinput-button")),
            array(array("innerwrapper" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "div", "class" => "controls")),
            array("Label", array("class" => "control-label")),
            array(array("outerwrapper" => "HtmlTag"), array("tag" => "div", "class" => "control-group"))
        );
```

But I still do not know how I can place an element with some content (for example with text):

```
<span>Add Files..</span>
```

And also I want to use drag and drop, but do not know how.

Comment: Learn the ViewScript decorator

Comment: Have a look at using a custom viewscript file.